# Editing CSV File - Delete entire similar values row based on condition VIA Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, export-to-csv, delete-row

Need to delete an entire row of a `CSV` file, when value of column A (i.e. `DevID`) equals value of column B (i.e. `ProdID`)

**My Code:**

```
$MergedFile= Import-Csv "C:\Users\d-mansings\Desktop\Mergedata.csv"

 $MergeTable=@{} 
   foreach($line in $MergedFile){
    if(Compare-Object $line.DevID $line.ProdID){
    echo "Not Matched, Keep the file as it"}
    else{ echo "Row need to be deleted"}
        }
```

In place of  `Row need to be deleted` I need a command that would delete an entire row.

Following is my `CSV` file:

```
"DevID","ProdID","cfname"
"-----","-----","------"
"10201","10202","Risk ID"
"10202","20202","Issue ID"
"10203","20203","Dependency ID"
"10204","20204","Server ID"
"10205","20205","Parent Application ID"
"10206","20206","Application Service ID"
"10207","20207","Application Supportability"
"10208","20208","Application Compatibility"
"10300","20300","Application Status"
"10301","20302","Contact ID Type 2"
"10302","20302","Contact ID Type 3"
"10303","20303","Contact ID Type 4"
"10304","10304","Business Service Manager"
"10308","20308","Server Location Name:"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter all entries where `DevID` not equals `ProdID` and pipe the result to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to save the csv back:

```
Import-Csv 'source.csv' | 
    Where { $_.DevID -ne $_.ProdID } | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'destination.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output:**

```
"DevID","ProdID","cfname"
"10201","10202","Risk ID"
"10202","20202","Issue ID"
"10203","20203","Dependency ID"
"10204","20204","Server ID"
"10205","20205","Parent Application ID"
"10206","20206","Application Service ID"
"10207","20207","Application Supportability"
"10208","20208","Application Compatibility"
"10300","20300","Application Status"
"10301","20302","Contact ID Type 2"
"10302","20302","Contact ID Type 3"
"10303","20303","Contact ID Type 4"
"10308","20308","Server Location Name:"
```

Comment: Worked !
thank you :)
I'm not able to mark it as answer currently, will do as soon as I have permission.