# delete a CSV rows based on column value in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I receive a CSV File everyday that has information I need, but i have to filter rows base on a different criteria for each row.

eg csv.

```
Name,Age,Date,Code
John,22,12/12/2020,5
Smith,16,12/01/2021,2
Jake,27,1/01/2020,1
Alice,18,2/02/2019,4
Fort,27,2/09/2021,2
Kevin,26,22/09/2019,5
```

I would like:

1. Remove all ages 18 and below in column 2
2. remove any dates past 2020 in column 3
3. Remove any codes that are 5 in column 5

My Result should be

```
Name,Age,Date,Code
Jake,27,1/01/2020,1
Fort,27,2/09/2021,2
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps a filter like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479625/editing-csv-file-delete-entire-similar-values-row-based-on-condition-via-power

Comment: Let us know if you were able to make progress using the link IronMan provided or if you still need assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$csv = @"
Name,Age,Date,Code
John,22,12/12/2020,5
Smith,16,12/01/2021,2
Jake,27,1/01/2020,1
Alice,18,2/02/2019,4
Fort,27,2/09/2021,2
Kevin,26,22/09/2019,5
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv.where{
    ($_.Age -le 18,
    [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, 'd/MM/yyyy', $null) -ge [datetime]::ParseExact('01/01/2020', 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null),
    $_.Code -eq 5)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBS8NAEIXv@yuGEoiFSZNdTLUFoSXaQ6UieCwiIRlMcJPVzZoq6m@Ps632Ig57@nhv3rx9NjuyXUVaR4WxNAxB0fVwAYuRuMkbwuUj4WXuCDNTklibqkWlUKqYn0pUgqm4a2pXoZx6mkhPJSqxzp8I1RnKH5agFEtdF4TyHFno7XKGp2JlrPNCZrNf8zX1NQdNOetAWZmK0QI@ITNtT9atrGmirOuF8AdPdhVZ@hDAcxI8TPhqiDQBR@3ZtuQKrm7ofj6/zW1HV2954bxy3w3CMt5s4neeECFoX7UeQ8Q7/vGFybFV6M1/3YdY3u@/DSJ6gXQsvobhGw)